# Converting array of strings to char multiple char * []

Tags: c++, arrays, allocation

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string text;
    string * OldArray = nullptr;
    string * NewArray = nullptr;
    unsigned int counter = 0;

    cout <<"Enter StringS" <<endl;
    while(true){
        cin >> text;
        if (text.find("End") != string::npos ) break;
        NewArray = new string[counter +1];
        for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
            NewArray[i] = OldArray[i];
        }
        NewArray[counter] = text;
        delete [] OldArray;
        OldArray = NewArray;
        counter++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i< counter; i++){
        cout << OldArray[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And I am supposed to write code that does exactly the same, but without including the `<string>` header.

So, basically, I have to write a string as `char []` and make the string pointers an array of pointers to multiple `char[]`.

The problem is, I have no idea how to do it correctly.

I would normally try to do something like this:

```
int counter = 0
char * charptr[500]; //this is gonna store adresses to some char[] 's 
char OurString[500]; //variable that will hold user's input
while(true){
    cin >> OurString;
    charptr[counter] = new char [500];
    charptr[counter] = OurString // mistake - charptr[counter] gets assigned physical adress of OutString while that's not exactly what we want
}
```

I would have to use some kind of function to copy data starting from some range of addresses. Any ideas how to do it this way?

Also, please notice that this solution forces me to create char array of fixed size, while, when using string, it is unnecessary to define size of string - isn't creating an array of chars capable of holding 500 characters a waste of memory comparing to string? If so, how is the problem solved in C language where there's no string class?

Comment: Why do you need this?  Why can't you use `std::string`? And why are you using raw arrays instead of using `std::vector`?

Comment: there is no magic that lets you store 500 characters in a `std::string` but it is a lot of hard-to-get-right boilerplate code around a c-style array. If you cannot use `std::string` best would be to write your own `my::string`, but really, why would you? You should rather add `#include <vector>` and get rid of that ugly `new` and `delete` ;)

Comment: *If so, how is the problem solved in C language where there's no string class?* -- I have to admit, the teachers today have really got some inventive ways of not teaching C++ in a C++ course.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do to what you are asking for, try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char text[500];
    char ** OldArray = nullptr;
    char ** NewArray = nullptr;
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    size_t textlen;

    cout << "Enter Strings: " << endl;
    while (cin.get(text, 500, ' ')) {
        if (strstr(text, "End")) break;

        NewArray = new char*[counter+1];
        for(int i = 0; i < counter; ++i) {
            NewArray[i] = OldArray[i];
        }

        textlen = strlen(text) /* or: cin.gcount() */ + 1;
        NewArray[counter] = new char[textlen];
        strncpy(NewArray[counter], text, textlen);

        delete [] OldArray;
        OldArray = NewArray;

        ++counter;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i) {
        cout << OldArray[i] << " ";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i) {
        delete[] OldArray[i];
    }
    delete[] OldArray;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would have to use some kind of function to copy data starting from some range of addresses. Any ideas how to do it this way?

The C++ standard library has an algorithm for copying. It is called `std::copy`. If you may not use the standard library, you can implement the same algorithm using a loop, the assignment operator and pointer arithmetic.

> isn't creating an array of chars capable of holding 500 characters a waste of memory comparing to string?

Yes.

> If so, how is the problem solved in C language where there's no string class?

In a similar way to how `std::string` itself is implemented; After all, `std::string` cannot be used to implement `std::string`. While the underlying data structure of `std::string` can be implemented in C just as well as in C++, the way memory is acquired and released is somewhat different because C has no classes or exceptions.

A string is just a special case of a sequence of objects - it is a sequence of characters. There are several resizable data structures that can represent a sequence. `std::string` and `std::vector` for example are implemented using a data structure called "dynamic array".

Dynamic array is implemented using a pointer, which points to a dynamically allocated array, and a record of the size of that array, as well as pointer to the last inserted element (or alternatively, number of elements). If the allocated space runs out, a new, larger dynamic array is allocated, the content from the old array is copied over, and the old one is released. It is important to grow the array at a geometric rate, in order to achieve constant asymptotic complexity (amortised) for insertion operation.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. If I understood correctly, string is somewhat like vector - I see it as a structure which contains - as you said - a pointer to the first element and a pointer to the last element. My question is, how does the element know if the data we're trying to store in the object exceeds the memory allocated for it? Like, some method assigned to operator '>>' in this struct?(and of course checking the number of elements in cin) I haven't really dug into ObjectOriented programming yet, but I would like to understand the general concept for now.

Comment: @JustAnotherPerson subtract the pointer to last element from the pointer to first element. Result is the number of elements (characters). Subtract that from the amount of memory that was allocated. Result is the memory remaining for new elements. Compare that to the number of elements being inserted.